# Display and Hide NavigationBar and ActionBar OnClick|Android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I want to hide and show the action bar and the navigation bar on click on the screen (I dont care where on the screen) and hide them after 2 sec.

I read that I can use this 
                  Handler h = new Handler();

```
               h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                // DO DELAYED STUFF
                   getActionBar().hide();
                 }
                 }, delaytime);
```

but My problem that on click nothing is happened.

another question I want The screen does not go black in no activity.

**EDIT**

---

I tried this

```
public void onUserInteraction() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onUserInteraction();
    getActionBar().show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            getActionBar().hide();

        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

but when I touch the screen the status bar shown. and only in sec touch the actionbar shows. The action bar goes after 1 sec but the status bar and navigation bar stay.
I dont want that the status bar and also I want that the navigation bar hide when the actionbar hides.

** I add the FULL SCREEN FLAG at the Oncreat artivity.
Thanks

**EDIT2**

---

```
public void fullScreenLandSpace(){
    //This function configure FullScreen and LandSpace Only!
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    getActionBar().hide();

}
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onUserInteraction();
    getActionBar().show();
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            getActionBar().hide();
             getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: use onuserinteraction() method

Comment: are you using `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` flag?

Comment: in your manifest ` android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"` is this theme used ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUserInteraction();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
                // Hide the status bar.
                int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        ;
                decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
                // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
                // status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
                ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
                actionBar.hide();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

//---------------------------------------------------
//add following code

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

//-------------------------------

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Comment: This is work only after to touch and not one. On first the navigation bar and status bar shows. on sec touch the action bar shows after one sec the action bar hide and the navigation and status bar stay on the screen. On third touch the navigation and the status bar hide.

Comment: remove fullScreenLandSpace() and use onUserInteraction() as i shown and inform me

Comment: The status bar still shown in the screen I dont want it at all

Comment: Thanks I found the problem I use vitamio and it makes conflict
I will change the code in the vitamio and then it work!
thanks